# Fixing Brackets Plugin written in Java Script

Tags: javascript, adobe-brackets

I have a Python script opened in Brackets. I press the `</>` (Run Script) button.

I get this Error:

```
python: can't open file 'C:/Users/Michael  Hofmann/...path.../tic tac toe/tic_tac_toe.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

The line `C:\Users\Michael Hofmann\...path...\tic tac toe>` appears.

When I enter `tic_tac_toe.py` it runs the script.

I think the problem is that there are `/` instead of `\`.

So now my question: Am I able to change the path output in brackets so it uses `\` instead of `/`?
Or am I able to tell the cmd that a `/` is also ok? 
And which one is the better solution.

**Edit:**
The problem seems to be the two spaces in the username. But Brackets is making them automatically... What to do?

**Second Edit:**
I found out that other people have this problem too. I know this is a lot to ask, but if someone knows Java Script can (s)he please fix it? [Here is the GitHub Link](https://github.com/saiintbrisson/source-scripts)

Comment: In my opinion, if you're not very attached to Brackets, you might want to try a more popular editor/IDE – I'd recommend Visual Studio Code https://code.visualstudio.com/ or PyCharm https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/

Comment: Forward slashes work on Windows too, they are not the problem here. Do you really have two spaces in your user name, though?

Comment: @AKX I really like Brackets and if I don't have to I don't want to use something else.

Comment: @tripleee No I don't have. So that causes the Error. But how do I change that?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the directory path of your tic_tac_toe.py file then run it

Comment: what do you mean?